# Word count returns 1 for empty file

Tags: java, count, cpu-word

This code is for counting words in the input. It works except when no words are in the input - it returns 1 and not 0.  What is wrong here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Input, Stop by #");
         String input = kb.nextLine();
         while (! input.equals("#")) {
             wordCount(input);
             input = kb.nextLine();             
            }
    } //main

    public static void wordCount(String countSpace) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int i =0; i < countSpace.length(); i++ ) {
            if ((countSpace.charAt(i)) == ' ') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);      
    }
} // class Exercise12
```

Comment: `int count = 1;` --> `int count = 0;`.I bet number of words are also #words+1

Comment: @smttsp theres one space between every two words, so while this would fix the issue with empty input, it'd create a problem for most other values.

Comment: @Paul, actually you are right. I jumped to the conclusion too fast without carefully thinking like everyone else in this question except you :)

Comment: Actually, he's probably getting correct results in most cases, because the last word doesn't have a space at the end.  Tokenisation would still be preferable in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get everything right you should `trim()` your `String` to remove leading and trailing whitespaces. Then `split` the `String` at whitespace and count all non empty `String`s. Empty `String`s are caused by consecutive whitespaces.

**Use Java 8:**

```
public static void wordCount(String countSpace) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(countSpace.trim().split(" ")).filter(word->!word.isEmpty()).count());
}
```

Comment: And if I have two consecutive spaces between words?

Comment: True. The java 8 solution works without counting consecutive spaces so i'll delete the other code

Comment: OP here went with your code but without the trim() this is for frist year at polytech thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use the split function like this:

```
public static void wordCount(String countSpace) {

    String[] words = countSpace.split(" ");
    int count = words.length;

    System.out.println(count);  

}
```

**EDIT:**

As @Jérôme suggested below, I added the trim function and a check for the empty input and now it works correctly. I also changed the string in the split function to the "\s+" regex, as @Aleks G suggested. Thak you for your corrections. See the updated code below:

```
public static void wordCount(String countSpace) {

    String[] words = countSpace.trim().split("\\s+");

    int count = 0;
    if (!(words[0].equals(""))){
        count = words.length;
    }        

    System.out.println(count); 
}
```

Comment: `trim()` the `String` before splitting and it will work fine

Comment: This won't work if there are tab characters between some words or multiple consecutive spaces. With split, you should use `"\\s+"` as the regex.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Use `StringTokenizer`:

```
public static void wordCount(String input) {
    int count = new java.util.StringTokenizer(input).countTokens();
    System.out.println(count);      
}
```

**Long explanation:**

Your code is almost correct, however you initialise your count to 1.  Then you increment it for every space character that you find. At the end of the input you do not have a space, thus you do not increment the count for the last word - and this compensates you starting with 1 and not 0.  Yet, in case of empty input, you start with 1 and there's nothing to read - therefore you end up with a wrong value.

The first fix is simple: change the initialisation to be `int count = 0`:

```
public static void wordCount(String countSpace) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < countSpace.length(); i++ ) {
        if ((countSpace.charAt(i)) == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);      
}
```

The next problem is that you're not counting words, but rather word separators.  What if there are two consecutive spaces between two words?  Further, what happens if you encounter end of line or end of file? Your code will break on those.

Ideally, you should use a tokenizer to count your words, but as a minimum, you should count how may times you switched from a space/line-end to an alphanumeric character.  Here's an example of using a Tokenizer:

```
public static void wordCount(String input) {
    int count = new java.util.StringTokenizer(input).countTokens();
    System.out.println(count);      
}
```

Comment: The function should count words, not spaces, so actually the initialization `count = 1` is correct for most cases, except the one where the input is empty. Consider for example "abc def ghi jkl". This contains 3 spaces, but 4 words. Nevertheless your code would return 3.

Comment: @Paul As I wrote in my answer, end-of-file and end-of-line need to be accounted for.  What if your input is "abc def\nghi jkl"? Then, initialising with 1 you will get 2 as a result.  I did indicate in the answer that a tokenizer is a better approach.

Comment: @Paul I added an example with tokenizer.

Comment: OP is using a `Scanner`, so there definitely won't be any newlines in the input in this case. Id say these may be the next step to write cleaner code, but aren't necessarily to get the correct values in this case. And you'd get 3 as output, which is actually correct, since we consider "def\nghi" as a single word (though it won't happen anyways).

Comment: @Paul Ok, what about a tab character?

Comment: @Paul you are mistaken.  Tokenizer on "abc" will return 1 - [check it yourself](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMaV9qM2xTWVN3RlU)

Comment: Sry, you're right. My bad. Either way, Id still say its preferable to stick to the level the OP is working on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the case of empty inputs separately. In addition you should keep in mind that an input might contain two consecutive spaces or spaces at the beginning/end of the line, which shouldn't count for words.

With these special cases, the code would look like this:

```
public static void wordCount(String in){
    boolean isspace = true;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++)
    {
        //increment count on start of a word
        if(isspace && in.charAt(i) != ' ')
        {
            count++;
            isspace = false;
        }
        //reset isspace flag on end of a word
        else if(!isspace && in.charAt(i) == ' ')
            isspace = true;
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

This code makes sure that words are only counted when they are actually encountered and repeated spaces get ignored.